# How do I display my ArrayList<Contact> contacts to my ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

So I am supposed to get user input for their name and number and add it to a list and display it to the ScrollView. However I don't know what else I am suppose to do in my last step to display it. I have a Main, Contact, and ContactsManager class.

```
Button      contactButton;
EditText    nameText;
EditText    numberText;
ScrollView  scrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    nameText = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    numberText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
    scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    final ContactsManager contactsManager = new ContactsManager();

    contactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enterText;
            String enterNumber;

            enterText = nameText.getText().toString();
            enterNumber = numberText.getText().toString();

            contactsManager.createContact(enterText, enterNumber);

            scrollView.getDisplay();
        }
    });
}

public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Contact(String nName, String NPhoneNumber) {
        this.name = nName;
        this.phoneNumber = NPhoneNumber;
    }

    public Contact() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}

public class ContactsManager {

    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

    public Contact createContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        this.contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        return contact;
    }
}
```

When I click the button to create contact nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the new contacts to your contact manager properly. Try something like:

```
public class ContactsManager {

    private List<Contact> contacts;

    public ContactsManager() {
        contacts = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialise the list once.
    }
    public Contact createContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        Contact contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber);
        contacts.add(contact); // Add the new contact to the list
        return contact;
    }
    // Use this to access all your contacts
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, you need to link your display with the list of contacts.

Comment: Ohhh okay, thanks I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So I learned that scrollView has to be a textView so I changed that to textView.getText() problem is I'm stuck trying to find the right syntax to put the List of contacts in here. I tried different approaches such as textView.getText(contactsManager.getContacts(List<>()); etc.

Comment: I imagine a text view accepts a string. So you probably want to use `textView.setText()` (not `getText()`) and convert your list to a string.